# Why does my code print off 18 instead of 10, and could you provide any solutions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python, just started learning at school at we've been given a task to complete, it asks for you to get a sentence and turn it into a list of words.

For example: 'ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY' would be recreated as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5]`.

But the example doesn't show what would happen if you had a new word added onto the end, and my teacher has asked me to have the last word appear as '10' if I were to use the example.

For example: 'ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY POTATO'. In my code it is outputted as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 18]`

My question is quite simple:

Why exactly does the code do this, and why doesn't it print it off as 10 instead of 18?

And is there any potential modification you could do to my code, and possibly show me but also explain how it works?

The following is the code I'm working with.

```
sentence = input("Please input a sentence that you want to find the locations of all words: ")
words = sentence.split()
print([words.index(s)+1 for s in words])
```

Comment: Because potato is the 18th word. You should eliminate repeating elements first.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980344/how-to-create-a-program-that-replaces-each-word-in-a-sentence-with-its-position or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980344/how-to-create-a-program-that-replaces-each-word-in-a-sentence-with-its-position or http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ASK+NOT+WHAT+YOUR+COUNTRY+CAN+DO+FOR+YOU+ASK+WHAT+YOU+CAN+DO+FOR+YOUR+COUNTRY+%5Bpython%5D

Comment: @Selcuk is exactly right. Try printing each individual word in addition to the index value to better see why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sentence, the list becomes:

```
['ASK', 'NOT', 'WHAT', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOU', 'ASK', 'WHAT', 'YOU', 'CAN', 'DO', 'FOR', 'YOUR', 'COUNTRY', 'POTATO']
```

`POTATO` is the 18th element.  You should create a new list with no duplicates:

```
singles = []
for word in words:
    if word not in singles:
        singles.append(word)
```

You can then use `singles.index(word)` instead of `words.index(word)`.  Even better:

```
used = {}
index = 0
for word in words:
    if word in used:
        print(used[word])
    else:
        index += 1
        print(index)
        used[word] = index
```

Yes, it's longer, but it is more efficient.

Comment: your second version is not quite doing the same thing, if you added a second `POTATO` to the end of the sentence it would show `10` for the first occurence then `18` for the second.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Very true.  I changed to a dictionary instead.

Comment: was in the process of suggesting a `dict` when my laptop battery died :)

Answer (score 1):

So here's your list of words, with the potato example:

```
>>> y = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY POTATO"
>>> words = y.split()
>>> print([words.index(s)+1 for s in words])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 18]
```

The reason it prints '18' is that the word "potato" hasn't appeared before, and there are 18 items in the list of words:

```
>>> for word_number, word in enumerate(words):
...     print(word_number+1, word)
...
1 ASK
2 NOT
3 WHAT
4 YOUR
5 COUNTRY
6 CAN
7 DO
8 FOR
9 YOU
10 ASK
11 WHAT
12 YOU
13 CAN
14 DO
15 FOR
16 YOUR
17 COUNTRY
18 POTATO
```

`index()` returns the *first time it finds that item in the list*. Potato wasn't in the sentence previously, so the last index is returned, which is 17+1.

Comment: if you are using `enumerate` you can specify `start=1` instead of adding 1 each time.

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

You're expecting your code to give you the index of the word without counting repeated words, but you're getting simply the word index in your original string.

#### The solution

First you need to get the **unique words** in the original string, so that you get the right word index *as per your needs*. You can try a [demo here](https://repl.it/CNvV/3). With the `Potato` extra word, it returns the index *10* instead of *18*, since it looks for it in the unique list, instead of the original one.

```
string = 'ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY POTATO'
words = string.split()
unique_words = []

#Remove the duplicates while preserving order
for word in words:
    if word not in unique_words:
        unique_words.append(word)
        
#Generate the indexes for the words
indexes = [unique_words.index(word)+1 for word in words]
print(indexes)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 9, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 10]
```